# Generate mysql data table with set of numbers (5/40 and 2/8)

Tags: php, mysql, numbers

I want generate build a table with probabilities of numbers as records, from 1 to 45 (similar to lottery format) and additional 2 numbers from 1 to 8, the result will be like 126m which I can add to my InnoDB mysql

I have no idea how to insert that huge number of data and prevent repetition, i found few examples online but where for SQL server, not MYSQL

Each number may go to a single column, something like id (AI) + 7 columns should accomodate it

example:

```
1. ---   1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5     1 . 2
2. ---   1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5     1 . 3
3. ---   1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5     1 . 4
. ----
. ----
. ----
9. ---   1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5     1 . 8
. ----
266. ---  1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 6 .   1 . 2
267. ---  1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 6 .   1 . 3
. ----
. ----
. ----
```

Anybody can help or clue a newbie here.. Thanks

Comment: Most simple is to make a number table(s) with 1 to 40 and a table with 1 to 8 and CROSS JOIN those table x times to get combinations to need

Comment: can you give example please? it is the all possible combinations I'm looking for... I tried the cross join didn't know how to manage

Comment: Change the parameters. Pretend the range is 1 to 4

Comment: well, I mentioned that I'm newbie, don't I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: "can you give example please?" Something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/1 or with ordering http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/3 ... You can direcly insert it into a other table with `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM ( sql from sqlfiddle ) AS alias`

Comment: Hi Raymond, I wan to create the table with possibilities of 5/24 and 2/8 numbers, just like have all lottery possibilities/combinations each one in a single raw/record.. i have a table with 1 to 45 numbers as field A and 1 to 8 as field 2.. example is in the question, any help is appreciated

Comment: @RaymondNijland i think you've nailed it but since it's a lottery the numbers from each table in the two groups should be different i.e. 1,2,3,...1,2 not 1,1,1...1,1. The query just needs a constraint to avoid duplicated numbers in each group. It's an elegant solution please post it so I can up vote!

Comment: "i think you've nailed it but since it's a lottery the numbers from each table in the two groups should be different i.e. 1,2,3,...1,2 not 1,1,1...1,1. The query just needs a constraint to avoid duplicated numbers in each group" The condition is pretty complex WHERE.. don't know if this comes anny comes i think it is check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/37

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't think the constraint needs to include group2 numbers vs group1 (based on OPs sample). So the constraint isn't quite so complex... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/38

Comment: Yes i think you are right @Nick but the also your WHERE condition will grow when more columns in the "group 1"  are needed.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think it can be simplified (and speeded up) by adding the constraint to the JOIN instead of using a WHERE condition http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/39

Comment: Does not matter both queries are optimized and executed the same @Nick Don't use the timing on sql-fiddle.com

Comment: @RaymondNijland didn't try an explain - was just going on timing from SQLFiddle. Regardless, I think one of those last two is a working answer to OPs question and you should post it.

Comment: "didn't try an explain" Ok.. @Nick did you know running `EXPLAIN query;` AND direclty after `SHOW WARNINGS;` you can see the "SQL" (it's not always valid SQL) after optimizing? (does not work on sql-fiddle) Check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pk5VyqQMYnSmA4hoefPis2/0 .. Then you can see both queries are rewritten (optimized) the same and executed.

Comment: @RaymondNijland no, didn't know that. thanks.

Comment: hello again, i read the comments but didn't understand the solution you guys are talking about, anybody can post clear answer to apply please...

Comment: Hi Mike, I think @RaymondNijland has solved your basic problem, just need him to post it as an answer...

Comment: Agree, @RaymondNijland please post an answer, thank you :)

Comment: @RaymondNijland please help out continue the thought, thanks

Comment: I wonder how we can contact @RaymondNijland to have a look and perhaps answers, i tried his profile couldn't reach out to him... still stuck and looked all over the net still couldn't manage to solve this... any further help is appreciated

Comment: @Mike could you not work it out from the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/38) demo?

Comment: iám having a vacation @Nick and the topicstarter... Check the SQLfiddles from me and Nick's SQLFiddle yhis one look ok http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/38 because there are two groups..

Comment: Hi, I did try all of my power of those SQL fiddle but still didn't understand it all, I see the select starts with number11, 12..etc. didn't get it.. was looking for really straight forward answer, i'm still newbie :(  enjoy your vacation Raymond, I will wait.. thanks guys :)

Comment: hi again guys, since Raymond is still on vacation, @Nick can you please explain a bit about this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/38 . why we started by using number11.number, what does that mean? --- can you please explain or just point out to simpler query that uses 1,2,3 as primery numbers and 1,2 as second numbers I will start with smaller data set to see how it goes then expand further.. I'm still waiting and watching this while didn't exactly yet finalized it... thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Mike, there is no straightforward answer, as it is a complex problem. Basically Raymond's solution creates two tables of numbers, one (`number1`) with all the numbers from 1-45, the other (`number2`) with all the numbers from 1-8, these being the valid numbers for each group. The `SELECT` then CROSS JOINS the first table 5 times (to allow for 5 numbers) and the second twice (for the 2 extra numbers).The 5 tables for the first group are called `number11`, `number12`, ... `number15`. The 2 for the second group are called `number21`, `number22`. The values selected are e.g. `number11.number`

Comment: So effectively the `SELECT` picks 5 numbers from table `number1` (1-45) and 2 from table `number2` (1-8). Then the `WHERE` clause makes sure that none of the numbers in each group are the same. Now for ease of typing Raymond didn't write the entire queries, where he has left `...` are places where they need to be filled in - the pattern should be obvious. There will also be additional clauses in the `WHERE` part to ensure the numbers from `number14` and `number15` are not the same as any others in that group. I hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your explanation dear. So assume i have those 2 tables which have the numbers, table (number1) 1-48 and table (number2) 1-8 and this select will cross join and give the results... assuming is correct, how to fill them in a new table? I'm sorry again I'm kind of newbie but if you be kind can you just post an answer with step, lets assume we have only 1-3 in table1 and 1-2 in table2, just to test it over, and i will continue adding numbers to the query/code and play with it until gives me the final table required.... really appreciated your patience..

Comment: hi again guys, what I did since yesterday I took closer look at this again: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/38,  used the explanation of Nick above to try to understand, so when almost I thought I did it, by minimizing to smaller group like only 3 main numbers and 2 extra to test...  but it gives lines like this: 1 - 2 - 3 - 1 - 2 . ( and next => ) 1 - 2 - 3 - 2 -1.. which is the same thing, it repeats the line but in changing places of the digits, i guess the where clause isn't working fine to prevent this.. here for advise please http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc055/38

Comment: :( still nobody